# Algebra Question ( possible values)

Tags: linear-algebra

If

> $$k = \dfrac{a}{b+c} = \dfrac{b}{a+c} = \dfrac{c}{b+a}$$

How many possible values of $k$ are there?

Answer (score 2):

Add like this:
$$(b+c)k+(a+c)k+(b+a)k=a+b+c$$
$$k=\frac{a+b+c}{b+c+a+c+b+a}=\frac12$$
if $a+b+c\ne0$, else $a=-(b+c)\Longrightarrow\dfrac a{b+c}=-1$.

So there are $2$ possible values for $k$, because first is e.g. for $a=b=c=1$ and the second e.g. for $a=b=1, c=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Addendo, $$k=\frac a{b+c}=\cdots=\frac{a+b+c}{b+c+c+a+a+b}$$

Now check if $a+b+c=0$ and it is not

Comment: I'm not sure how you did that

Comment: @user140139, do you know $$\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac{a+c}{b+d}?$$

Comment: I do not. And I still don't get how many possible values k has

Comment: @user140139, please go through  http://ckrao.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/manipulating-fractions/